# Using Plotly to create choropleth map of Canada

Tags: plotly

Here is my dataset:
[image]
Name of the dataset is gas_try.

I am using geojson file that I downloaded from [here](https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/georef-canada-province%40public/export/?disjunctive.prov_name_en).

My code to create the choropleth map is:

```
prov_data = gpd.read_file("canada-province.geojson")
figure1 = px.choropleth(gas_try,
                      geojson=prov_data,
                      locations="GEO",
                      color="Value",
                      color_continuous_scale="YlOrRd",
                      range_color=(gas_try["Value"].min(), gas_try["Value"].max()),
                       labels = {"Value" : "Oil Prices"}
                    )
```

and I only see this as an outcome.
[image]
Can someone tell me where I went wrong? This is my first time using plotly and geopandas, so I may have made some stupid mistakes.
Thanks for your help and have a great rest of your day! :D

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your full code: did you import everything correctly? What is the structure of 'gas_try' dataframe?, Also, you did not properly follow the example offered by Plotly: https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

prov_data = gpd.read_file("canada_provinces.geojson")

merged_df = prov_data.merge(gas_try, how='left', left_on='name', right_on='<COLUMN CONTAINING PROVINCE NAME IN GAS_TRY>').set_index("Province").fillna(0)
fig = px.choropleth(merged_df,
geojson=merged_df.geometry,
locations=merged_df.name,
color="Value",
scope="north america",
range_color=(merged_df["Value"].min(), merged_df["Value"].max()),
color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Bluered,
title = 'Something about gas'
)
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":50,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue using this same GeoJSON file.

You need the featureidkey argument, as the province names are listed in the GeoJSON file under the property "prov_name_en". (EDIT: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492092/im-making-a-choropleth-map-with-plotly-express-how-do-i-match-up-the-values-in?rq=1).) Also, see this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719643/plotly-express-choropleth-only-shows-one-color) for some information; this particular file needs to be unwound first.

A working form should be:

```
from geojson_rewind import rewind
prov_data = gpd.read_file("canada-province.geojson")
fixed_prov_data = rewind(prov_data,rfc7946=False)

figure1 = px.choropleth(gas_try,
                      geojson=fixed_prov_data,
                      locations="GEO",
                      color="Value",
                      color_continuous_scale="YlOrRd",
                      range_color=(gas_try["Value"].min(), gas_try["Value"].max()),
                      labels = {"Value" : "Oil Prices"},
                      featureidkey = "properties.prov_name_en" 
                    )
```